# Session management using Express & MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, session

I have a website which needs to manage three things, a basket, an account and a checkout process.

- **Basket:** Needs to be maintained for 14 days so customers can come back later without their items disappearing.
- **Account:** The customer signs in for access to their account. Needs to be maintained for 20 minutes (end automatically after 20 minutes of inactivity).
- **Checkout:** The checkout process where customers buy the contents of the basket. Again needs to be maintained for 20 minutes.

I'm using Node, Express and MongoDB. I have a session setup using `express-session` and `connect-mongo`, which works fine. The sessions are maintained in a `sessions` collection which has a MongoDB `_id`, which is used as the session id (accessed via `req.session` in express route handlers).

I have the `ttl` set at the default in the [config](https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo#session-expiration), which is 14 days. This works great for maintaining the basket.

My question is, how do I manage the account and checkout timeouts at 20 minutes, without killing the whole session..?

Is the only way to manage a manual flag/datetime in the session, which must be manually updated every time the user the does something..?

Is there an easier way..?

**Update, to be more clear**

I have 4 MongoDB collections: `sessions`, `baskets`, `accounts`, and `checkouts` (not the real names of my collections!). A session document is created when someone visits the website, with a ttl of 14 days, so if you don't come back within 14 days the related session document is deleted, which kills the session.

When you sign in with a username and password from your account, the session is updated to hold an auth flag, which is cleared on sign out.

When you start the checkout process, a checkout document is creating linking back to the current session.

So, at the moment a session lasts for 14 days, which means if you sign in, your login session timeout is also 14 days, but I need this to be much shorter.

Comment: I imagine the basket, account and checkout are somehow related to the session from the context of the question, but the nature of the relation is unclear. It may also explain a bit what accounts are. Can't believe the user accounts are deleted after 20 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: The basket, accounts and checkout are all related to the session, but I need different timeouts for each. An example is Amazon I think, where it saves your basket contents for quite a while (many days), but your account times out (logs you off) after a shorter period of time for obvious security reasons. Maybe my question isn't worded very well - sorry!

Comment: Account usually refers to the user record - the lifetime data that keeps persisten user's information, e.g. login credentials. When user logs in, Amazon creates a new session, which indeed expires after short period of time. You didn't shed any light of how exactly these things are related, so it's hard to advise anything. From technical point of view, TTL index applies to documents, so if you want to delete different entities they should be different documents.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I've updated my question. Does that help..? You say "When user logs in, Amazon creates a new session"... So that implies that Amazon doesn't hold the basket contents in a session, or they have two different sessions, one to hold basket contents (when someone is not signed in), and one for the login.

Comment: Anything stops you to create TTL indexes for each collection? So documents in `baskets` will be removed after 14 days, documents in `checkouts` will be removed after 20 min etc.

Comment: I'm using [connect-mongo](https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo#remove-expired-sessions) which sets the ttl on the `sessions` collection for me. In any case, that wouldn't help with logins as the auth flag is currently in the session, not in a separate collection which can be auto-removed. I may need a rethink how I'm doing all this.......

Comment: First of all "inactivity" implies you need to extend expiration time on each "activity" event. Connect-mongo approach seems to be a bit limited in this regard. There is no magic in TTL indexes if you [check it in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/). I would recommend to set `expireAfterSeconds` to 1, and defined expiration time field in each document, like 14 days in the future, 20 minutes in the future etc. It's way more flexible, as you can update it depending on your app's logic at any time.